# Lipschitz inequality required for Broyden convergence proof

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to understand the proof of the convergence of the Broyden method through the book [Numerical Methods for Unconstrained Optimization and Nonlinear Equations](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53411241/Numerical-Methods-for-Unconstrained-Optimization-and-Nonlinear-Equations-Classics-in-Applied-Mathematics#scribd), and at some point the proof relies on the following lemma (page 77):

**Lemma 4.1.15** Let $F$, $J$ satisfy the conditions of Lemma 4.1.12. Then, for any $v, u \in D$,

$||F(v)-F(u)-J(x)(v-u)|| \leq \frac{\gamma}{2}(||v-x||+||u-x||)||v-u||$

For context, $J$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$ and Lemma 4.1.12 says the following:

**Lemma 4.1.12** Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be continuously differentiable in the open convex set $D \in \mathbb{R}^n, x \in D$, and let $J$ be Lipschitz continuous at $x$ in the neighborhood $D$, using a vector norm and the induced matrix operator norm and the constant $\gamma$. Then, for any $x+p \in D$,

$||F(x+p)-F(x)-J(x)p|| \leq \frac{\gamma}{2}||p||^2$

You can find the proof of $4.1.12$ [here](https://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/lectures/L8-BT-convergence.pdf), page 13.

Unfortunately, the proof of Lemma 4.1.15 is left as an exercise to the reader and I'm unable to figure it out. By manipulating the initial expression, I can show that

$||F(v)-F(u)-J(x)(v-u)|| \leq \frac{\gamma}{2}(||v-x||^2+||u-x||^2)$

but this is not the required inequality.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Letting $p = v-u$, we have
\begin{align*} \| F(v) - F(u) - J(x)(v-u)\| & = \| F(u+p) - F(u) - J(x) p\| \\
& \leq \| F(u+p) - F(u) - J(u)p\| + \| J(u)p - J(x)p\|.
\end{align*}
The first term can be bounded using Lemma 4.1.12 by 
\begin{align*}\frac{\gamma}{2} \|p\|^2 & = \frac{\gamma}{2} \|v-u\| \|v-u\| \\
& \leq \frac{\gamma}{2} \left(\|v-x\| + \|u-x\|\right) \|v-u\|.
\end{align*}
The second term can be bounded since $J$ is Lipschitz,
\begin{align*}\|J(u)p-J(x)p\| & \leq \|J(u)-J(x)\| \|p \| \\
& \leq \gamma \|u-x\| \|v-u\|.
\end{align*}
So, we get the result if we enlarge the constant a bit.

Answer (score 0):

So the person who did it isn't wrong but isn't right either. First, recall what Lipschitz continuous means

$$
Lip_\gamma (x)
$$

means $\gamma$ is the best constant that satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| \le \gamma|x-y|$

Now, for this problem, you need to think about change in variable.

$
\|F(v) - F(u) - J(x)(v-u)\|  = \|\int_u^v J(z)dz - J(x)(v-u)\| \\
= \|\int_u^v( J(z) - J(x) )dz \| \\
 = \|\int_0^1 (J(u + t(v-u)) - J(x)) (v-u)dt\|
$

For this, I let $z = u + t(v-u)$ so $dz = dt(v-u)$. I want to integrate from 0 to 1 to make my life easier. Now, think about adding 0. The text book you are using shows many different ways of adding 0.

$
u + t(v-u) = u + t(v-u) + xt - xt \\
 = u(1 - t) - x(1-t) + t(v-x)
$

Now insert this back into the integral.

$
\|\int_0^1 J(u + t(v-u)) - J(x) (v-u)dt\|  = \|(v-u)\int_0^1 (J(u(1 - t) - x(1-t) + t(v-x)) - J(x) )dt \| \\
 \le \|(v-u)\int_0^1 \gamma(u(1 - t) - x(1-t) + t(v-x)-x )dt \|
$

Do the integration and you will get your answer. The main idea is to figure out WHERE and HOW you add 0.